# Nissan transmission test port - M10x0.9 thread?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, modification

2004 Nissan Xterra automatic transmission. Was trying to install an Autometer Trans Temp into the fluid pressure test port... realized that OE test port plug bolt is M10 x 0.9 thread?? Never even heard of that pitch for an M10... usually extra fine is M10x1.0

My trans temp sending unit is 1/8 inch NTP, was able to get an M10x1.0 adaptor, which I was certain was going to work, but alas. Any ideas??

In case folks don't believe it's 0.9 and not 1.0, here is the bolt:
[image]

I also tried to thread a new M10x1.0 bolt in and it didn't want to go in at all. So yes, definitely 0.9!

Comment: Are you sure it's M10x0.9?  I think it's more likely the standard M10x1.0.

Comment: Take the port plug to the hardware store and have the threads measured.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's 0.9. Added picture with thread-meter to my post. I even tried to thread in a new M10x1.0 bolt thinking I was crazy and it was just going to work but it didn't want to go in at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the plug is tapered it is no M10x1.0.

I think it is a 1/8 BSPT: 0.907mm pitch, 9.728mm outer diameter and tapered.

NPT to BSPT adapters are widely available at car part shops.